# Is there any way to install Windows Phone 8 SDK without Express IDE?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, certificate, sign, windows-phone-8-sdk

I need to set up a machine to sign .XAP files to be distributed on a private company. I can sign apps on my dev machine as I've got VS on it, but the sign server shouldn't have all the IDE installed.

Is there a way to install only the needed files to sign apps?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You cannot just install signing tools. You have to install the Visual studio tools, VS 2013 update 3 which contains Windows Phone 8.1 SDK or install WP 8.0 SDK.

For Windows Phone company app distribution, you also have to precompile the managed assemblies before signing.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn168929(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: Thank you! We finally managed to do it with a Jenkins slave server running windows and the SDK